# Pass data from CLASS component to FUNCTIONNAL component REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to pass some data but cant access it in my functional component.

Once user submit a login on my Class component:

```js
return (
  <Redirect
    to={{
      pathname: '/home',
      userName: this.state.name,
      state: { userName: this.state.name },
    }}
    userName={this.state.name}
  />
);
```

I want to get the `userName` data in a functional component but can't access it, I tried `this.props` etc (but its not a class) and all props, location, history etc return `undefined`.

Comment: Read up on [functional components here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). A functional component receives `props` as its only argument. So you would declare it like this `function MyComponent(props)`. And then just use it as a variable, not with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i didn't used it correctly before .. such time wasted but learning everyday, huge thanks @Brian Thompson for the answer i link the doc he gave :
[Functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)